# Setting the appearance of just one UIToolbar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, customization, uitoolbar

I have two toolbars stacked on top of each other. They are created programmatically. The bottom bar uses standard UIButton elements with a solid colour background and the buttons inherit the tint.

I want the toolbar above it however to have a background image. I can only get this to work by using the appearance setter, however the appearance property is applied to both toolbars. Can anyone see a way around this?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

///top toolbar///



UIToolbar *toolbar2 = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-84, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
toolbar2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:toolbar2];
UIImage *testimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:testimage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:testimage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];


///////bottom toolbar////


UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,    self.view.bounds.size.height-44, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
toolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithHexValue:0xff336600];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"help.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openHelpView)];
button1.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"web.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openWebView)];
 button2.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openFBView)];
button3.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UIBarButtonItem *button4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openTwitterView)];
button4.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

[toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,spacer,button3,spacer,button4,spacer,button2, nil]];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Just created an empty subclass of the UIToolbar class and then created my top Toolbar from that instead. That way I can apply the appearance property separately.